# I found a forged version of Stack Overflow!

Tags: discussion

I found a spoofed (*forged*) version of Stack Overflow using the 'dot in' top level domain, that could be used for phishing. The site looks just like SO but it's not! And may have dangerous content.

The page events (scroll for example) are hacked to redirect to advertising.  ***And more nasty stuff!***

When I tried to scroll down something really deceptive appeared: from the forged site I was re-directed to a page that said my computer was 'infected with a virus' and gave a phone number purporting to be Microsoft that I should ring to fix my computer!

Don't navigate to the link, unless you're prepared to handle the offensive nature of the site, of which I may only be reporting a small part.

```
http://www.stackover.in/questions/tagged/mvcsitemapprovider?page=5&sort=votes&pagesize=15
```

The URL was listed on the fist page of Google results, so I reported it to Google and SO's form 'contact support'.  Which seems less than sufficient...

Who else should I report this to?

What else should be done to eliminate this rubbish/danger from the web?

What will SO do once I've notified them?

Comment: Not at all the same the site above is falsely trying to mimic SO and linking to harmful content.

Comment: I don't believe that the appropriate action is any different.

Comment: For example who's responsibility it it to tell microsoft? Can the phone number be used to track the people doing this?

Comment: Not at all the same as scraping, this is Phishing with a clone (look alike ) site that has absolutely NO information value.  This is not a licencing issues, but more scam/ criminal use of the SO site / design.

Comment: Have you navigated to the site?

Comment: @StephanLuis the license allows sites to reuse Stack Overflow content as long as the honor the license requirements (which include attribution requirements).  Chances are a site of this nature is not honoring those requirements, so the solution is the same as any other scraper.

Comment: @StephanLuis I really have no interest in going to the site.  Did you even read the duplicate (and the question is quotes)?  It explains what to do.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Spoofing and scraping are completely different and I'm suggesting that reporting to SO, search engine providers, and domain name hosting providers should be different.  The designation of responsible party (SO or user) for reporting should be clear and easy to find...and currently it is not.

Comment: You've been told several times what the process is. How is that not "clear and easy to find", then? The only issue is that you're refusing to follow the process for reporting scrapers. Just report the scraper. Then let SE deal with it, and move on with your life.

Comment: ... it's not a scraper but a spoof-- used for deceptive reasons!

Comment: @StephanLuis true, it's completely different in what it DOES. But it violates the license in the same way and will most likely be closed on THAT ground, so report it like that and it'll be properly handled.